# How to add different materials to different parts of a texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm not sure how to separate different parts of a texture into different materials. For instance, if I wanted to make the 'B' in the image below glossy, and leave the rest of the texture matte, how would I go about doing that?

[image: logo]

Comment: try to use the texture to control the roughness value of the material and take a look at tutorials about nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try it this way:

- Prepare 3 pictures: the original B, a B&W B to use as a cache to make the glossy appear, and normal map picture.
- Mix a *Diffuse* (with the original picture) with a *Glossy* shader, use the B&W picture as a factor in the *Mix Shader*.
- As the *Glossy* shader may seem a bit dark, mix it with an *Emission* shader, but I guess the glossiness will depend on your environment, so you might not need that.
- Load your normal map in an *Image Texture* node (*Non-Color Data* mode), plug it into a *Normal Map* node, plug this node into the normal sockets of the *Diffuse* and *Glossy* nodes.

[image]