# Texturing-Is a good ideea to split an object in multiple parts?

Tags: texturing

I created a book and i want to texture it.I unwraped the object and i don't know how to put the textures (i have a texture for each cover and also for the pages and  for the back).I can assing these texture for each part or i must split the book in multiple objects (with P) and then to textue every part.[image]

Comment: Don't, just learn how to *unwrap* the object properly: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6757/31447

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140156/how-to-add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-texture https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26588/multiple-materials-with-different-textures